# Ruby for Rails collection_select not submitting fields to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using two collection_select helpers on a page. The lists themselves get populated correctly but when I go to submit the form  NULL is passed to the Insert. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. UPDATE: Added Controller code

New.html.erb:

```
<h1>New map_apps_suite</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', map_apps_suites_path %>
```

Form Code:

```
<%= form_for(@map_apps_suite) do |f| %>
  <% if @map_apps_suite.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@map_apps_suite.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this map_apps_suite from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @map_apps_suite.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div>
        <%= f.label "Application Name:" %>
        <%= collection_select(:death_burrito_application, :id, DeathBurritoApplication.all, :id, :death_burrito_name, :prompt => true) %>
    </div>
        <br>
        <br>
    <div>
        <%= f.label "Project Name:" %>
        <%= collection_select(:custom_product_suite, :id, CustomProductSuite.all, :id, :product_suite_name, :prompt => true) %>
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Log:

> Started POST "/map_apps_suites" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Sep 02 20:57:10
>   -0700 2011   Processing by MapAppsSuitesController#create as HTML
>   Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create Map apps suite",
>   "death_burrito_application"=>{"id"=>"3200"},
>   "authenticity_token"=>"0PP2U50CScjTbcUdRgbIjkExqo9k3psjlcf4w61ZpqI=",
>   "utf8"=>"✓", "custom_product_suite"=>{"id"=>"1"}}   [1m[36mSQL
>   (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m   [1m[35mSQL (13.0ms)[0m  describe
>   `map_apps_suites`   [1m[36mAREL (22.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO
>   `map_apps_suites` (`custom_product_suite_id`,
>   `death_burrito_application_id`) VALUES (NULL, NULL)[0m   [1m[35mSQL
>   (44.0ms)[0m  COMMIT Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/map_apps_suites/3 Completed 302 Found in 185ms

Controller Code for Create, New:

```
class MapAppsSuitesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_apps, :only => [:new, :edit, :destroy, :update]
  before_filter :get_suites, :only => [:new, :edit, :destroy, :update]

  def get_apps
    @applications = DeathBurritoApplication.order(:death_burrito_name).all
  end

  def get_suites
    @custom_prod_suites = CustomProductSuite.order(:product_suite_name).all
  end

  def new
    @map_apps_suite = MapAppsSuite.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @map_apps_suite }
    end
  end
  def create
    @map_apps_suite = MapAppsSuite.new(params[:map_apps_suite])
    Rails.logger.debug("Params: " + params.inspect)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @map_apps_suite.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@map_apps_suite, :notice => 'Map apps suite was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @map_apps_suite, :status => :created, :location => @map_apps_suite }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @map_apps_suite.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please provide the controller side code so that one is able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to save in your `custom_product_suite_id` and in `death_burrito_application_id` your `map_apps_suites table`

You can save this using either of following two ways

1] change html and remain controller code as it is

```
<%= collection_select(:map_apps_suite, :death_burrito_application_id, DeathBurritoApplication.all, :id, :death_burrito_name, :prompt => true) %>


 <%= collection_select(:map_apps_suite, :custom_product_suite_id, CustomProductSuite.all, :id, :product_suite_name, :prompt => true) %>
```

OR Just add `f.` to collection_select

```
<%= f.collection_select(:death_burrito_application_id, DeathBurritoApplication.all, :id, :death_burrito_name, :prompt => true) %>


 <%= f.collection_select(:custom_product_suite_id, CustomProductSuite.all, :id, :product_suite_name, :prompt => true) %>
```

2] change the create method like following and remain html as it is

```
    @map_apps_suite=MapAppsSuite.new(:custom_product_suite_id=>params[:custom_product_suite][:id], 
                             :death_burrito_application_id => params[:death_burrito_application_id][:id])
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! #1 worked and now I realize my error in thinking. I had tried the f.collection_select and kept getting a merge error so thought I was barking up the wrong tree.